# Jquery draggable not working 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I'm trying to make an element draggable with jquery but it's not working here is the code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <style>
        #console {
            background-color: #000000;
        }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="console">

       </div>
      <script>
          $(function() {
              $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
         });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `element` to drag. There isn't any such element with `id` `draggable` for which you have instantiated `dragging`. I presume you want to drag `div` with `id` `console` and hence you need to initialize `draggable` on that particular element like `$( "#console" ).draggable();`. Below is the working snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $("#console").draggable();
});
```

```css
#console {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="console">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is written to `#draggable` but this id is not defined.

Here is the working code with example

**HTML**

```
<div id="console" class="draggable">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#console {
  background-color: #000000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

> Above i am using draggable class because you are already using console if in div you can change it accordingly

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/fn12kq4o/1/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You don't have any id defined as draggable in your html
2. You have no content in your #content for the background to show in black.

Try something like and give some height to your console say 100px. You should see the effect of draggable

```
<div id="draggable">
 <div id="console">

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your set dreggable to "#draggable" element but there is no such element in the html. so i changed #draggable to #console

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#console {
background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="console" style="width:20%;height:50px;">

</div>
      <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#console" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Draggable needs an element ..There is not a element with id draggable in Your code..

Try this code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="draggable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable {
background-color: #000000;
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
              $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
         });
```